# Get OpenGL Handle of external process

Tags: java, opengl, process, jna, handle

I want to draw an overlay on a specific program, like some recording-programs (Fraps, Bandicam, ...) do. I knew I had to grab the process-handle of the running program somewhere.

Is it possible to grab the handle of an OpenGL process on windows through java? And if yes, how?

(I read something about JNA somewhere, but I did not quite understand it.)

Comment: You are going to need to do more than grab a process handle for this, you need to hook into the `SwapBuffers (...)` procedure. There really is no other way to reliably overlay something to a GL window.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for the answer! Do you think this will be hard to achieve? Or could it be rather simple with JNA? I'm, like, really new to this stuff, since I've never ever used things like the Windows API...

Comment: I have no idea how you would do this in Java, unfortunately. I know how to do this in C, but it is pretty complicated - it involves injecting code into OpenGL32.dll at run-time. The other option is to place a custom OpenGL32.DLL in the application's working directory before it begins, while that is considerably easier, it is not very robust.